# Prove by induction on n that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac {k+2}{k(k+1)2^{k+1}} = \frac{1}{2} \ - \frac1{(n+1)2^{n+1}}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, induction

> $$
> \sum_{k=1}^n \frac {k+2}{k(k+1)2^{k+1}} = \frac{1}{2} \ - \frac1{(n+1)2^{n+1}}
> $$

Base Case:

I did $n = 1$, so..

LHS-

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac {k+2}{k(k+1)2^{k+1}} = \frac3{8}$$

RHS-

$\frac{1}{2} \ - \frac1{(n+1)2^{n+1}} \ = \frac3{8}$

so LHS = RHS

Inductive case-

LHS for $n+1$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac {k+2}{k(k+1)2^{k+1}} +\frac {n+3}{(n+1)(n+2)2^{n+2}}$$

and then I think that you can use inductive hypothesis to change it to the form of
$$
\frac{1}{2} \ - \frac1{(n+1)2^{n+1}} +\frac {n+3}{(n+1)(n+2)2^{n+2}}
$$
now form here I tried multiplying it out and solving with some algebra but I kept hitting dead ends. If you could explain your steps and the reasoning behind them I would appreciate it.

Comment: Hint: $\frac{n+3}{(n+1)(n+2)2^{n+2}}
= \frac{2(n+2)-(n+1)}{(n+1)(n+2)2^{n+2}}
= \frac{2}{(n+1)2^{n+2}} - \frac{1}{(n+2)2^{n+2}}
= \frac{1}{(n+1)2^{n+1}} - \frac{1}{(n+2)2^{n+2}}$

Comment: Alright, this might be completely off, but is it $\frac{n+5}{(n+2)(2^{n+2})}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{split}
D &= \frac {n+3}{(n+1)(n+2)2^{n+2}} - \frac1{(n+1)2^{n+1}} \\
  &= \frac{1}{(n+1)2^{n+2}} \left[\frac{n+3}{n+2} - 2 \right] \\
  &= \frac{1}{(n+1)2^{n+2}} \times \frac{n+3-2n-4}{n+2} \\
  &= \frac{1}{(n+1)2^{n+2}} \times \frac{-(n+1)}{n+2} \\
  &= \frac{-1}{(n+2)2^{n+2}}
\end{split}
$$
Can you finish?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what's happening in your second step, could you explain? Also where did the 1/2 go? Sorry if this is really obvious, I'm still learning

Comment: @Brownie first line just writes down the two terms, the second one factors out the denominator and the highest power of $2$, leaving no powers of $2$ in the first term and $2^1 = 2$ in the second one, since $2^{-(n+1)} = 2 \cdot 2^{-(n+2)}$. Does that help?

Comment: yes it does, thank you!